# What is a Dependency Injection Container?

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am trying to understand the role of a Dependency Injection Container because it strikes me as fundamental in maintainable code.

As I understand it, a DIC is just as the title suggests: a container where all your dependencies are collected together. Instead of seeing `new Foo\Bar` all over the application, all the new instances are generated inside of the container and then passed through to each other where they are needed (e.g., `Model` is instantiated with an instance of `Database`, which is instantiated with an Instance of `Config`).

I have attempted to make a *very simple* DIC. This is the result.

In my front controller I am instantiating a new `App\Core\Container`.

My `Container` looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Core;

use App\Config;

class Container
{
    public $config;
    public $router;
    public $database;

    public $model;
    public $view;
    public $controller;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->config   = new Config;
        $this->router   = new Router;
        $this->database = new Database($this->config);
    }

    public function add()
    {
        // add dependencies from the outside?
    }

    public function getInstance(/* string */)
    {
        // return an instance for use somewhere?
    }

    public function newModel($model)
    {
        $model = $this->getModelNamespace() . $model;
        $this->model = new $model($this->database);
        return $this->model;
    }

    private function getModelNamespace()
    {
        $namespace = 'App\Models\\';
        if (array_key_exists('namespace', $this->params = [])) {
            $namespace .= $this->params['namespace'] . '\\';
        }
        return $namespace;
    }

    public function newView($params)
    {
        $this->view = new View($this->model, $params);
        return $this->view;
    }

    public function newController($controller)
    {
        $controller = $this->getControllerNamespace() . $controller;
        $this->controller = new $controller;
        return $this->controller;
    }

    private function getControllerNamespace()
    {
        $namespace = 'App\Controllers\\';
        if (array_key_exists('namespace', $this->params = [])) {
            $namespace .= $this->params['namespace'] . '\\';
        }
        return $namespace;
    }
}
```

**Questions**

- Could my implementation above, although very simple, be classed as a basic dependency injector?
- Is a Dependency Injection Container generally comprised of one class?

Comment: I'm curious about this as well. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255771/how-can-i-use-dependency-injection-in-simple-php-functions-and-should-i-bothe) I believe the container should be dependency agnostic (as opposed to just hard-coding them), which leads me to believe your implementation is wrong. However, the comments on that answer indicate it's an anti-pattern, so that implementation may be wrong as well... +1 hoping for a good answer.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link... If no one responds I guess I might put a bounty on it...

Comment: This might also help you: "To get the benefits of Dependency Injection you need to keep pushing the creation of dependencies up through the code until it reaches the top." http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/07/07/dependency-injection-moving-from-basics-to-container/ The top is the bootstrap file. Is Container.php your bootstrap file?

Comment: Great, that is a useful comment, thanks!

Comment: This is not a dependency injection container. It's really a poor factory. I'll try to write an answer

Comment: If you could also flesh out why it is a 'poor' factory that would be appreciated ('cause thats how we learn!), thanks for your time!

Comment: I'll leave [**http://stackoverflow.com/a/27037936/736809**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461846/when-can-dependency-injection-containers-become-too-big-and-what-can-i-do-about) here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> <sub>**Note:** the first three headings answer your questions, while the following ones answer anticipated questions and provide coverage of anything in the first two sections.</sub>

### Could this be classified as a dependency injection container?

No, this does not look like a dependency injection container. A dependency injection container is meant to **reduce the work that instantiation requires by determining, creating, and injecting all dependencies.** Rather what you have there appears to be a combination of a factory and a service locator.

**Factories** abstract the creation of objects. This is essentially what your `Container` class is doing. By calling designated methods (i.e., `newModel`), your container takes on the responsibility of locating the exact object to be instantiated and constructing an instance of that object.

The reason I would call this a "poor" factory is that it's beginning to look like it might be used to locate services. **Service locators** work by hiding an object's dependencies: instead of being dependent on `GenericService`, an object might depend on a service locator. Given the service locator, it can request an instance of `GenericService`. I see similar behavior beginning to take hold in your `add()` and `getInstance()` methods. Service locators are generally considered anti-patterns because they abstract dependencies therefore making code impossible to test!

### Is a dependency injection container comprised of one class?

*It depends.* You could very easily make a simple dependency injection container with one class. The issue is that the nature of a *simple* container tends to get more advanced into a *not-so-simple* container. When you start improving your pattern, you need to consider how the different components play together. Ask yourself: do they follow SOLID principles? If not, refactoring is necessary.

### What is a dependency injection container?

I said it above, but again: a dependency injection container is meant to reduce the work that instantiation requires by determining, creating, and injecting all dependencies. A DIC will look at all dependencies of a class, and all dependencies those dependencies may have, and so on... In this sense, the container is responsible for **hierarchically instantiating all dependencies**.

The `Container` class you provide relies on very strict definitions of pre-defined classes. For example, classes in your model layer appear to *only* be dependent on a database connection. (Similar statements can be said about classes in your controller & view layer).

### How does a dependency injection container find dependencies?

A dependency injection container will detect dependencies. Typically this happens through 1 of 3 mechanisms: autowiring, annotations, and definitions. PHP-DI docs provide a good idea of what all three of these entail [here](http://php-di.org/doc/getting-started.html#defining-injections). In short, though: autowiring detects dependencies by [reflecting](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) on a class, annotations are used to write in dependencies using comments above a class, and definitions are used to hard-code dependencies. Personally, I prefer autowiring because it's clean & simple.

### Can I create a simple dependency injection container or no?

Yes, you can. Start with the idea that an injector should be able to instantiate any object (service, view, controller, etc...). It needs to look at the relevant object and hierarchically instantiate all dependencies (hint: possibly through some method of recursion).

A quick example of a simple injector using autowiring looks like this:

```
<?php
class Injector
{
    public function make($className)
    {
        $dependencies = [];

        //Create reflection of the class-to-make's constructor to get dependencies
        $classReflection = new ReflectionMethod($className, "__construct");

        foreach($classReflection->getParameters() as $parameter) {
            $dependencyName = $parameter->getClass()->getName();

            //Use the injector to make an instance of the dependency
            $dependencies[] = $this->make($dependencyName);
        }

        $class = new ReflectionClass($className);

        //Instantiate the class with all dependencies
        return $class->newInstanceArgs($dependencies);
    }
}
```

Tested with something like the following, you can see how the injector recursively checks and instantiates all dependencies

```
class A {
    protected $b;
    public function __construct(B $b) { $this->b = $b; }
    public function output(){ $this->b->foo(); }
}

class B {
    protected $c;
    public function __construct(C $c) { $this->c = $c; }
    public function foo() { $this->c->bar(); }
}

class C {
    public function __construct() { }
    public function bar() { echo "World!"; }
}

$injector = new Injector;

$a = $injector->make("A");
//No need to manually instantiate A's dependency, B, or B's dependency, C

$a->output();
```

This basic injector has obvious faults. For example, there is an opportunity to create a recursion disaster if two classes are dependent on each other (there should be a check for that). However, as is, this works as a *basic* example of what an injector looks like.

#### Injector vs. Dependency Injection Container

To make this more powerful and fall under the definition of "dependency injection container", you'd want a way to share instantiated instances across multiple `make()` calls. For example, you may have another method called `share()`. This method would store the instance passed to it. Whenever a class is built through the `make()` method and depends on a class previously shared, instead of instantiating a new instance, it would use the already-instantiated one.

For a simple & powerful dependency injection container I suggest [Auryn](https://github.com/rdlowrey/auryn), but by all means, try to understand & create your own before using the ones already available.

Comment: I think it would be nice if your answer included a code example. Seems strange that this was immediately accepted as the answer with no real-world basic example.

Comment: Although a code example would be nice, this answer is well-written (enough for me to understand what a dependency container does at least) and now I will be able to ask more pointed questions.

Comment: The code examples are really clear, thanks for taking the time to give such a well written answer. Very good teaching!