# Access database from the parent class

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new to the Slim Framework and I'm trying to build a simple webapp connected with PDO to a MySQL database (and with a Twig/Bootstrap UI).

I try to access database from a controller named "PagesController" :

```
class PagesController extends Controller {
    public function getLieu(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response) {
        // this two lines crash :
        $lieux = $this->$database->query('SELECT * FROM Lieu');
        var_dump($lieux);

        $this->render($response, 'pages/lieu.twig');
    }
}
```

But I'm only able to call my PDO object from index.php or **the from the parent abstrat class named "Controller"** :

```
class Controller {
    private $container;

    public function __construct($container) {
        $this->container = $container;
        // those 3 lines works well :
        $database = $this->container->get('db');
        $lieux = $database->query('SELECT * FROM Lieu');
        var_dump($lieux);
    }

    public function render(ResponseInterface $response, $file) {
        $this->container->view->render($response, $file);
    }
}
```

Is somebody here can help me ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `database` property *protected*.

Also: `$this->$database` is wrong. Correct is `$this->database`.

Be aware that your class design is based on the *service locator* antipattern. E.g. you are passing the whole container to your controllers in order to get the database object from it. Don't do this! Inject only the resources that a class needs. E.g. your controller should receive only the database instance as dependency. Take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ojsn11XY0X8&feature=youtu.be), [this](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/18/breaking-the-law-of-demeter-is-like-looking-for-a-needle-in-the-haystack/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702676/what-is-a-dependency-injection-container) and, especially, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0).

You don't actually want to inject the database instance either. You should inject it into proper [data mappers](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html). And the data mappers should be injected into the controllers. In principle, the process of accessing data from a persistence layer is the responsibility of more MVC components. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895805/properly-calling-the-database-from-model-in-an-mvc-application). And this serie for code examples involving domain objects, database adapters, data mappers, repositories and services: [Part 1](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-a-domain-model/), [Part 2](https://www.sitepoint.com/integrating-the-data-mappers/), [Part 3](https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-collections-of-aggregate-roots/) and [Part 4](https://www.sitepoint.com/an-introduction-to-services/).

A note: in Slim you can use the Eloquent ORM. See [this](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/cookbook/database-eloquent.html).

Suggestion: You should learn OOP before starting (using) an MVC and familiarize yourself with the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) too.

```
class Controller {

    private $container;
    protected $database;

    public function __construct($container) {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->database = $this->container->get('db');

        $lieux = $this->database->query('SELECT * FROM Lieu');
        var_dump($lieux);
    }

    public function render(ResponseInterface $response, $file) {
        $this->container->view->render($response, $file);
    }

}

class PagesController extends Controller {

    public function getLieu(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response) {
        $lieux = $this->database->query('SELECT * FROM Lieu');
        var_dump($lieux);

        $this->render($response, 'pages/lieu.twig');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very munch for your response! You made my evening.
The main problem was the "$" behind database.


Yes I felt that give the database object to every controller may not be a great idea. I'll watch and read your links to understand more how to build a great MVC application. Thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome. I reedited with more links (a serie with code examples) and a suggestion.